# SendGrid suppression/bounces provides no results []

Tags: sendgrid-api-v3

When trying to retrieve suppression or bounces using SendGrid API 3, I get no results.

- I did contact SendGrid support and they confirmed that the API key is logging in successfully
- I was able to send email using the same API key
- When you login into the account on the web site, you can see suppression and bounces (global)
- I also tried this route "suppression/unsubscribes" and get the same result `[]`

I am only interested in downloading all global bounces or unsubscribes.

[image: Console program with Sendgrid result]

```cs
string queryParamsBounce = @"{
                               'end_time': 1, 
                               'start_time': 1
                             }";
var responseBounce = await client.RequestAsync(method: BaseClient.Method.GET, urlPath: "suppression/bounces", queryParams: queryParamsBounce);
Console.WriteLine(responseBounce.StatusCode);
Console.WriteLine(responseBounce.Body.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
Console.WriteLine(responseBounce.Headers.ToString());
```

Comment: `start_time` and `end_time` are epoch times, why are you sending `1` as the value? Use https://www.epochconverter.com/ to get the values you need to use. Also these parameters are optional. So you can skip sending them all together and try

Comment: Those numbers come from the official github sample to retrieve all suppression bounces:
https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/main/examples/suppression/suppression.cs

Comment: Did it work without the parameters?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Does your key have **Full Access** and if not, did you enable **Suppression** read/full access for this key? https://prnt.sc/xrhwnk Try to create a new API key with **Full Access** for testing this (*Don't forget to delete it after testing*).

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the queryParams from the api request as below:

```
var response = await client.RequestAsync(method: SendGridClient.Method.GET, urlPath: "suppression/blocks");
```

Or change the endtime parameter to a time in future. e.g. `'end_time':2212920280`